# Match all strings except master | dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I want to create a regex that can match all strings except a set, something like:

```
/[^master|dev]/
```

basically the string would match the regex if the string wasn't the literal "master" or "dev", anyone know how? The above is pretty much completely wrong..

```
console.log(
  /^master|dev/.test('master')
);
```

and so is that.

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative lookahead:

```
/^((?!(master|dev)).)*$/
```

This just matches the string - if you want to match the word:

```
/^((?!\b(master|dev)\b).)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing individual strings that you don't want to find
any of those items in, it would be something like

`^(?!.*(?:master|dev)).+$`

If testing the string does not exactly equal one of these, it is this

`^(?!(?:master|dev)$).+$`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using logical NOT operator (`!`) ?

```
let input = "this is the input";

let excludeSet = ["master", "dev"];    

let regexp = new RegExp(excludeSet.join("|"));

// if `input` does not match string in `excludeSet`
if(!regexp.test(input)) {
}
```

Comment: sure, but with my set of regexes, I won't know whether to use not or not, the regexes have to be stored in a config file as strings.